# Where is this icon coming (svg?) from which is used by mapbox

Tags: svg, icons, mapbox-gl-js

I saw a mapbox custom control icon but no idea what the format is or where it is coming from.  I would like to use a different icon but do not know where to look or how to incorporate.

Here is the code from mapbox that places a home icon:

```
        <button>
            <svg 
                focusable   = "false" 
                viewBox     = "0 0 24 24" 
                aria-hidden = "true" 
                fill        = "black" 
                style       = "font-size: 20px;">
                <title>
                    Legend
                </title>
                <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z">
                </path>
            </svg>
        </button>
```

In particular, what is this:   `<path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z">`  I assume it pulls the home icon.  Where can I see a list of other icons available?  What is the format?  How do I understand path?  Not sure where to look.  I think the icon comes from [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=home) but not sure.

Any help much appreciated.